# Broadcast receiver in fragment called 3 time send only once

Tags: android

I am creating sending broadcast from activity to fragment. But in my case receiver called three times as I only send broadcast once. please help

Here , I am registering broadcast in Fragment

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter("example.com"));

}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
}
```

And my receiver in Fragment

```
 BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Here I am receiving the data and want to update the list in 
        //my fragment
  };
```

Sending the broadcast

```
Intent intent = new Intent("example.com");
intent.putExtra("data","any_data");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: have you tried debugging the code??

Comment: is your fragment in viewpager?

Comment: Yes I debug the code so many times .. Always the debugger is going 3 times in the receiver @sourabhkaushik

Comment: @ManthanPatel Yes my fragment is in viewpager as I am creating fragments dynamically according to the tabs

Comment: then try to register and unregistered broadcast in setUserVisibleHint

Comment: please post your both class from where you are sending broadcast and where you are receiving that

Comment: @sourabhkaushik sending broadcast in api response .. where the api is getting the status code 200 . and i checked this method is called only once

Comment: dude please post the code or else do not expect that  you'll get answer here no one can answer without full info

Answer (score 0):

You must always set Action to `Intent` like below,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("action_type");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And in your receiver add this line :

```
BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getAction("action_type")) {
      // Write your code here now.
    }
};
```

Hope it works.